# Can a correlated subquery be replaced by an inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Given that I'm asking about a small subset of possible uses of a correlated subquery...

I'm working with a vendor product that uses a lot of correlated subqueries.  My task is to modifiy the queries to make them meet our business needs.  The vendor's queries appear to be overly complicated and difficult to maintain.

One simple example...

```
select e.EmployeeLastName
, e.EmployeeFirstName
, e.EmployeeRecordEffectiveDate
, e.EmployeeRecordEndDate

from Employee e

where e.EmployeeLastName like 'a%'
  and exists (
       select 1
       from Position p
       where p.PositionId = e.EmployeePositionID
  )

order by e.EmployeeRecordEffectiveDate
;
```

...can be replaced by a simpler query using an inner join...

```
select e.EmployeeLastName
, e.EmployeeFirstName
, e.EmployeeRecordEffectiveDate
, e.EmployeeRecordEndDate

from Employee e
  inner join Position p on p.PositionId = e.EmployeePositionID

where e.EmployeeLastName like 'a%'

order by e.EmployeeRecordEffectiveDate
;
```

Of course, most of the queries are more complicated.  For example, replace the `Position` table with a subquery - but keep the main structure.

Are there risks involved with making the queries simpler?  (maybe involving NULLs...)
Is there an advantage to using a correlated subquery?

Comment: As Gordon already pointed out, your change for that one is fine so long as `p.PositionId` is unique; otherwise, you'll end up with multiple results for each match.

Comment: If there is a foreign key enforced between `Employee` and `Position`, you could go one better and replace the `exists` with `and e.EmployeePositionID is not null`.

Comment: Why is this question tagged both `[oracle]` and `[sql-server]`? Are you really using two RDBMS platforms?

Comment: I'm using both platforms and I wanted to be sure to get feedback from both Oracle experts and SQL Server experts, in case there was a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Position(PositionId)` is unique, then your two queries are equivalent.

I'm not sure that you will get any performance benefit.  `EXISTS` is usually fine from that perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I would compare the execution plans between the queries that have correlated subqueries and those that have them replaced with a join.  While in many cases correlated subqueries can lead to performance issues if not written properly, there are others where they can actually perform better.  For example, a NOT EXISTS subquery usually performs better than a LEFT JOIN ... WHERE [column] IS NULL, while EXISTS subqueries typically perform the same as simple INNER joins.

With that being said, you should compare the performance differences on an individual basis by replacing the correlated subqueries with joins one-by-one.